A generic error occurred in GDI+ on Bitmap Save - Azure
I get "System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.' (on save)
" when running
private void SaveImage(string base64, string imageName)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
    {
        using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))
        {
            bm2.Save(imageName, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}

on azure. The base64 strig is correct since on https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image it's decoding fine. I'm running it on azure functions.

Are you sure the error happens on save? And are you sure imageName is valid?

I notice that you have tagged this as an Azure issue but there's nothing in the question that indicates that the problem is specifically related to Azure. Have you tried the same code in a simple Console app to see whether the same thing happens? That's the sort of thing you need to have done for yourself before posting a question here.

What happens if you seek to the beginning of the stream before saving? That's a bit of a guess but it's worth trying.

do you get this error every time you run the code, or just occasionally?

Can you provide full code and where re you getting base64 string, its bit confusing can you provide full details

Post the full exception text, not just the type and message. The full text contains any inner exceptions and a stack trace that shows the chain of calls that led to the exception.

The problem was the path. so the solution is to use Path.Combine and Path.GetTempPath

private void SaveImage(string base64, string imageName)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
    {
        using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))
        {
            bm2.Save(imageName, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}

var fileName = ...
var filePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
SaveImage(base64, filePath);



You wouldn't get an error if you used just a file name. The file would be saved locally. You'd get an error if you tried to save to a read-only folder though.
